# Have an "active" filter when loading listView

Tags: ng-admin

I have a huge database that takes ages to load when loading it through listView(). Is it possible to activate and apply a filter with a default value (now() on a field having a date, to get only today's records) before loading the data?

There is a ".defaultValue()" function, but it's just for displaying *after* the page has loaded and the user has clicked to add a new filter...

Comment: What kind of database? SQL? If so, can't you adjust the SQL request (at server side!) appropriately just to deliver what you are interested in?